# Search 3 web pages from one user entry (xamarin forms)

Tags: forms, url, xamarin, browser

I have four tabbed pages (Amazon, Google, and eBay), while the last one is my HomePage. The HomePage has a user entry with a search button below. I want to have the users input be searched on all three web pages(tabbed pages) at the same time. Is there anyway to pass the "entry/input" into the other three pages url? Ex. "(-) + (user entry)" . If someone wants to purchase a new laptop for instance... The first page would take the input and add it to the URL of each page. .... Essentially, webview=("https://www.google.com/" + laptops) and so on for the other two tabbed pages. Hope I explained my question well enough! Thank you all way in advance!!!!

**====This is my HomePage.Xaml====**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.HomePage"             
             Title="Home">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Home Page"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Entry x:Name="search1" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
             HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" Text="Search" 
             VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Entry x:Name="sms" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                    Text="Send Text" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**===This is my HomePage.Xaml.cs===**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App2
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = sms.Text;
        }

        public void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = search1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

**===This is my Google.xaml===**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Views.Google"
            xmlns:Content="clr-namespace:App2.Views.HomePage"
             Title="Google">
    <StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Button Text="&lt;" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="45" 
             Clicked="Back_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="&gt;"    HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="45" 
             Clicked="Forward_Clicked"/>
            <Entry  x:Name="URL" WidthRequest="197"/>
            <Button Text="Go"  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="55" 
             Clicked="Go_Clicked"/>

        </StackLayout>

        <Label x:Name="LoadingLabel" IsVisible="False"/>
        <WebView x:Name="Googlepage" HeightRequest="1000" 
         WidthRequest="1000"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**===This is my Google.xaml.cs===**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using App2.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App2.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Google : ContentPage
    {
        public Google()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            URL.Text = ("https://www.google.com/");
            Googlepage.Source = "URL.Text";
        }

        private void Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Googlepage.CanGoBack)
                Googlepage.GoBack();
        }

        private void Forward_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Googlepage.CanGoForward)
                Googlepage.GoForward();
        }
        private void Go_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Googlepage.Source = URL.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are definitely other ways to do it but one way that comes to mind is a static variable which contains the search text. Then when your user clicks on each tabbed page, when that page loads, just perform the specific search URL including the search text from the static variable.

Comment: Thanks for responding! But can you give me an example in the Xaml / xaml.cs? I'm extremely new to this, I'm sure you can tell, so it's ok if you repsond like I'm 5 years old haha. Ive got a lot to learn still!

Comment: @Dizzlee sure, give me a few minutes. I also upvoted your question so it's at 0 because someone down voted it. And I hate when people down vote but don't give feedback why.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!!! This seems like it should be easy ... But I've spent a lot of time searching with no luck! Also, you're going to laugh at me haha, but what do you mean someone down voted me? And what's it mean when you upvoted me? (That aside, thanks for upvoting my post !!! Even if idk what it means yet)

Comment: Also, if you'd like... I can just send you all of the code I have so you can take a look at where I am in the app? Im Not very far so the code isn't cumbersome yet.

Comment: Honestly, it might be a good idea to add your code to your question to show what you have done so far. You dont have to include your personal website link if you dont want to. There's a couple ways you could do that, you could add the project to a public repo on something like github and share the link. Or you can separately post the code directly in here. Just give each code snippet a title, paste the code, highlight the pasted code, and click the code tags and it will be formatted when you save your question.

Comment: ok. after forever and a half of formatting this code to try and make it look presentable for you, I finally have it down and ready for your expertise!!! (Thank you again!!! so so much!!!!!!!!!)

Comment: In my Google.xaml.cs page, i want to have the source....which is URL.Text to have "https://www.google.com/" + the entry from the home page. So then when the user goes to the google tab page, it will show the google search page with the results of whatever they wanted to look up. All being done by the "Search" button on the HomePage. (That way the google page will already have the search results populated prior to the user even going to the google tab page) i hope that wasn't confusing/worded in a weird way!

Comment: I know I am probably annoying at this point haha, but some of the code isnt relative to this particular problem i have. (i.e. the sms.text, send button, etc... ) that is a future problem i will have. but that is future me's problem !

Comment: Okay @Dizzlee I created an example which uses a tabbed view with a tab containing your entry for putting in search terms, and then 4 tabs for Amazon, Google, Ebay, and your custom website.

This is just an example and there are MUCH better ways to go about this so this is to just get you started and thinking.

Comment: I created a repo for it here:  https://github.com/schwaggs/WebViewTabbed.git

So you can download the zip and see how I did it. If you need any clarification or explanation post your questions in here so others can see.

Comment: OMG thank you so so so much @Schwagmister!!!!!! You are a life saver!!! I will be going though the code to try and understand what you did for future use! again, Thank You so much!!!!!

Comment: @Dizzlee If it does in fact do what you need and you understand what I'm doing please accept it as an answer. You can also provide a final comment with what worked for you specifically for anyone viewing the post in the future.

Comment: Everything you did/ wrote worked!! The code on GitHub works flawlessly!!! The add-ons I'm working on are forward, back, go buttons and a url entry (basically the bar at the top of any web browser). Anyone in need of an answer to a similar problem ... Refer to schwagmister 's github post!

Comment: @Dizzlee glad it met your expectations. Again, there are much better ways to do what I did especially if you plan to release an app to production.

If you wouldn't mind it might be beneficial to update your question with anything relevant from my repo that may be helpful in the future. Just in case that repo we're to be deleted or something.